# c# console get array value with index from user input

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm in an intro to programming class. Is it possible to output an array value when a user selects its index? Its not much but this is my code so far:

```
double[] cisTuition = new double[] { 0.00, 1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50 };
Console.WriteLine("Please choose the semester");
```

Comment: Hi Jade - Are you asking to simply print out (ala, `WriteLine` or similar) one of the values in your array?  Akin to `Console.WriteLine(cisTuition[0])` printing out `0.00`?

Comment: Hint: you can access the value of an element of an array by its index. Ex. cisTuition[n], when n is the index number. Remember that arrays are indexed starting at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access using index of the array

```
Console.WriteLine(cisTuition[index]);
```

For example, if you need to get the index from the user entered input value,

```
int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("value is: " + cisTuition[input]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reach an value inside and array at a particular index position as below:

```
double[] cisTuition = new double[] { 0.00, 1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50 };
Console.WriteLine(cisTuition[0]);
```

Ouput:

```
0.00
```

Then, as you requested to have an index provided by an input, I would use `Console.ReadLine()` to get the user choice and record it into a variable (`index`).

Lastly, I would use the variable as index with `cisTuition[index]`.

See the full code below:

```
double[] cisTuition = new double[] { 0.00, 1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50 };
Console.WriteLine("Enter input:"); // Prompt the question
string index = Console.ReadLine(); //  Record the input
Console.WriteLine(cisTuition[index]); // Show the array value of this index
```

Comment: Yes, but how would a user be able to select the index with like a Console.ReadLine()?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get the value of the `cisTuition` array by their index: Check the snippet below

```
double[] cisTuition = new double[] { 0.00, 1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50 };
Console.WriteLine("Please choose the semester");

int index = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("value is: " + cisTuition[index]);
```

Of course, you can improve that snippet validating that the index is inside the bounds of the array, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
    bool Keeplooping = true; //Boolean to tell whether the loops continues
    while (Keeplooping == true) //while the user hasn't chosen a valid index
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Select an index");
    try //if this fails then the input is not an int or too big/small
    {
    int index = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //receive input
    Console.WriteLine(cisTuition[index].ToString()); //output the value
    Keeplooping = false; //loop will end after this iteration
    }
    catch //alerts user that the input is bad and tries again
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please select a valid index");
    }
    }
```

This should do the trick (I tested it already to be sure)

Comment: Instead of using `Keeplooping`, you can just use `break` instead

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance I do agree, but at the time I answered this I wouldn't have known that, I haven't been programming for long and am constantly learning, so back then I didn't know what a break was.

Answer (score 0):

Well first you need the users input, when you got this you can do your proper checks, like is it NaN, or if it's outside the arrays index. After this it should be easy for look out the index in the array and then print it. I dont program that much in C#, but i guess it could look something like:

```
double[] cisTuition = new double[] { 0.00, 1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50 };
Console.WriteLine("Please choose the semester");

var UserInput = getUserInput();

if(UserInput == NaN || UserInput > cisTuition.length)
return()

print( cisTuition[UserInput] )
```

I know this is definitely not the correct syntax, but the logic should work.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is being missed here is how to read in a value, convert it to an `int` if possible, and then use that as the reference to the array index.

So, if that's the case, you'd want something akin to this added to the end of your code:

```
string strUserInput = Console.ReadLine();
int? iConverted = null;
int.TryParse(strUserInput, out iConverted);
if ((iConverted != null) && (iConverted <= (cisTuition.Length - 1)) )
{
  Console.WriteLine(cisTuition[iConverted]);
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid value or index of the array");
}
```

Full explanation:

`ReadLine()` pulls in the value the user provides as the index to the array

`iConverted` is instantiated (as null) to start, to allow an integer to also be null we have to use the `?` as well

We `TryParse` the `strUserInput` into an Integer, and dump it into `iConverted` if successful (if not, `iConverted` remains null)

Finally, we print the requested index array, or notify the user that their index was out of bounds, or not properly parsed.

Comment: AFAIK `iConverted` would have to be an `int?` for it to be able to store `null`